# How to get the sum of row in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a written a query which is giving following output

But my actual need is something different

```
TRANSACTION_DATE    DETAILS          LEAVE_CREDITED LEAVE_DEBITED
29-Sep-2012      Sep-2012-Sep-2012        0.11  
01-Oct-2012      Oct-2012-Dec-2012        2.5   
01-Jan-2013      Jan-2013-Mar-2013        2.5   
31-Mar-2013      LAPSE - 540007                        1.9
01-Apr-2013      Apr-2013-Jun-2013        2.5   
30-Apr-2013      Lev_102935703                        0.11
```

There should be a 5th column such that

Its value should be LASTBALANCE+(Leave_Credited)-(Leave_Debited)
In this case

```
BALANCE
0.11-0=         0.11
0.11+(2.5-0)=   2.61
2.61+(2.5-0)=   5.11
5.11+(0-1.9)=   3.02
```

Please help.

My query is something like

```
SELECT TRUNC(NVL(C.UPDATED_DATE, C.CREATED_DATE)) TRANSACTION_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(C.SERVICE_START_DATE, 'Mon-YYYY') || '-' ||
       TO_CHAR(C.SERVICE_END_DATE, 'Mon-YYYY') Details,
       C.LEAVE_CREDITED,
       NULL LEAVE_DEBITED
  FROM LEAVE.GES_LEV_CREDIT_DETAILS C, LEAVE.GES_LEV_CREDIT_MASTER CM
 WHERE C.LEV_CREDIT_ID = CM.LEV_CREDIT_ID
   AND C.PERSON_ID = 12345
   AND CM.COUNTRY_LEAVE_TYPE_ID = 5225
     AND c.leave_credited<>0
UNION
SELECT TRUNC(NVL(d.UPDATED_DATE, d.CREATED_DATE)) TRANSACTION_DATE,
       d.reference,
       NULL,
       d.no_of_days LEAVE_DEBITED
  FROM LEAVE.GES_LEV_CREDIT_DETAILS C,
       LEAVE.GES_LEV_CREDIT_MASTER  CM,
       leave.ges_lev_debit_req_dtls       D
 WHERE C.LEV_CREDIT_ID = CM.LEV_CREDIT_ID
   AND C.LEV_CREDIT_DETAIL_ID = D.LEV_CREDIT_DETL_ID
   AND C.PERSON_ID = 12345
   AND CM.COUNTRY_LEAVE_TYPE_ID = 5225
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 5.11+(0-1.9)=   3.02

Shouldn't it be 3.21.

Use Analytic **SUM() OVER()** for both credited and debited columns and then take the difference of them.

Let's see a working test case, I have built your table using **WITH** clause, in reality you just need to use your table instead of **DATA**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('29-Sep-2012', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, 0.11 LEAVE_CREDITED, NULL LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('01-Oct-2012', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, 2.5  LEAVE_CREDITED, NULL LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('01-Jan-2013', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, 2.5  LEAVE_CREDITED, NULL LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT to_date('31-Mar-2013', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, NULL LEAVE_CREDITED, 1.9 LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT to_date('01-Apr-2013', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, 2.5   LEAVE_CREDITED, NULL LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT to_date('30-Apr-2013', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') TRANSACTION_DATE, null LEAVE_CREDITED, 0.11 LEAVE_DEBITED FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT t.*,
 10    SUM(NVL(leave_credited,0)) OVER(ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE)
 11     -
 12    SUM(NVL(LEAVE_DEBITED,0)) OVER(ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) LASTBALANCE
 13  FROM DATA t
 14  /

TRANSACTI LEAVE_CREDITED LEAVE_DEBITED LASTBALANCE
--------- -------------- ------------- -----------
29-SEP-12            .11                       .11
01-OCT-12            2.5                      2.61
01-JAN-13            2.5                      5.11
31-MAR-13                          1.9        3.21
01-APR-13            2.5                      5.71
30-APR-13                          .11         5.6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT t.*,
  SUM(NVL(leave_credited,0)) OVER(ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) 
   - 
  SUM(NVL(LEAVE_DEBITED,0)) OVER(ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) LASTBALANCE
FROM table_name t                                                  
/
```

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B
Thanx a lot but
The calculation is getting wrong if the TRANSACTION_DATE are same.

Comment: for duplicate dates, if you want a specific order, then you must have another key to sort it.

Comment: Yeah got it sir,thatnxx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

*I am using Oracle.*

> You can use sum() over (order by transaction_date) to get a running
>   total - which will handle the lapsed leaves etc. ->

*Output:*

[image]

*Script:*

```
select to_date(transaction_date) transaction_date, details, 
leave_credited, leave_debited, 
sum(leave_credited - leave_debited) over (order by to_date(transaction_date) asc) final_balance
from
  (select '29-Sep-2012' transaction_date,
    'Sep-2012-Sep-2012' details,
    0.11 leave_credited,
    0 leave_debited
  from dual
  union all
  select '01-Oct-2012' , 'Oct-2012-Dec-2012' , 2.5 , 0 from dual
  union all
  select '01-Jan-2013' , 'Jan-2013-Mar-2013' , 2.5 , 0 from dual
  union all
  select '31-Mar-2013' , 'LAPSE - 540007' , 0, 1.9 from dual
  union all
  select '01-apr-2013' , 'apr-2013-jun-2013' , 2.5, 0 from dual
  union all
  select '30-Apr-2013' , 'Lev_102935703' , 0, 0.11 from dual
  );
```

Comment: `TRANSACTION_DATE` must be a DATE data type. It is a bad design to store dates as strings. While displaying, you just need to use `to_char`.

Comment: Agreed. @LalitKumarB - The focus here was not on the date format (I've used explicit conversion in the outer query). Also, it is not always up to the reporting analyst to maintain date formats. Sometimes, people have to work with flat files - with different date formats

Comment: Hmm. I just thought to point that out if you have not noticed. anyway, if you are aware of it, then it is good.